# I need to verify that suggestion list in coveo's search suggests correctcly

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, autosuggest, coveo

So, yes, I tried to locate suggestion magic box by css selector in **Selenium**, tried to send DOWN key to select suggested values, tried to find element's tag by JavaScript but nothing helps. 
All that I found is that element lay somewhere here.

`div[class='magic-box-suggestion coveo-omnibox-selectable']`

But trying to get all children from that element return 0 elements. I tried to Google that problem, but didn't found anything.

Comment: Share the html code and what you have tried in code so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution! Here we are:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[./span[@class='coveo-omnibox-hightlight']]"));
```

This code returns `List<WebElement>` that contains all `span` elements in Coveo's magic-box-suggestions.

This **JavaScript** code helped me to find a locator for Coveo's autosuggestion query. Just execute this in the browser's console.

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('div.magic-box-suggestions');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation);
    });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```